# How can i use getelementsbytagname in a xml file without get nested elements?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an xml file like this one:

```
<result>
    <entry>
        <id>0001</id>
        <name> john doe </name>
        <comments>
              <entry>
                  <text>blablabla</text>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                  <text>blablabla</text>
              </entry>
        </comments>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>0002</id>
        <name> mario gomez </name>
        <comments>
              <entry>
                  <text>blablabla</text>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                  <text>blablabla</text>
              </entry>
        </comments>
    <entry>
 </result>
```

I want to get the all the 'entry' elements but the nested elements that have the same name inside the comments tag.

I'm using this:

```
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText,'text/xml');
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
```

but with that i get all the elements with the "entry" tag, even the children of comments.

the xml is a file that i'm getting from a server and i can't change it

How can i get only the 'entry' parent elements?

Comment: Have you tried xPath?

Comment: Are the `entry` elements you want always children of the root?  Are there ever non-entry elements as direct children of the root?

Comment: Sorry i'm a novice i don't even know what is xPath. Can i use it in javascript? In that case how can i do it?

Comment: Yes the entry elements are always children of the root. There are never non-entry elements as direct children of the root

Comment: I finally solved the issue using xPath. Thanks for your help.